# Compare in real time letter for letter as you type

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write a code that compares in "real time" the world that the user introduce in an input box with a given word (i.e "house"). When the letter written is correct, the whole word is in blue, when the user introduce a wrong letter the word becomes red.

This is the html:

```
<input id='inputtype' onkeyup='return validateAsYouType(this);' />
```

**EDIT: Solved!** Here is the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function validateAsYouType(inputElementId)
{
var val = inputElementId.value;
var randomWord = "house";

if (val.length <= randomWord.length && val == randomWord.substr(0, val.length)) {
document.getElementById("inputtype").style.color="blue"; // If right, put it in blue
}

else { document.getElementById("inputtype").style.color="red"; // If wrong, put it in red
}

if( val == randomWord)
{
    document.getElementById("inputtype").style.color="#339933"; // If right, put it in green
}

}
```

Comment: "how can I compare in real time letter for letter as you type?"

Comment: Since you solved the question yourself, please consider posting it as an accepted answer, so that people with the same issue will see it straightaway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the typed word is not longer than the given word, and that the typed word so far is the same as the corresponding letters in the given word:

```
if (val.length <= randomWord.length && val == randomWord.substr(0, val.length))
```

You would also need an `else` for the `if` statement to also change the color when the word is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function validateAsYouType(inputElementId)
{
    var val = inputElementId.value;
    var randomWord = "house";

    var elem = document.getElementById("inputtype");

    if( val == randomWord)
    {
        elem.style.color="#339933"; // If right, put it in green
    }

    else
    {
        elem.style.color="blue"; //if wrong, put it in blue
    }

}
```

Not a lot of change from your code, just an `else` that shows "real time" checking

[Test Link](http://jsbin.com/asoyey/1/edit)

Comment: thanks, but this make all the text red, I want that the text is blue when right.

Comment: When the user is typing the text should be blue? and when it's correct it should be green?

Answer (score 0):

Under the bit that checks to see if the whole word is correct, make character arrays from your words (`val` and `randomword`), and then loop through one array comparing the current char with the same numbered char from the other array.

Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= val.length; i++)
{
  if (valArr[i] != randomwordArr[i])
  document.getElementById("inputtype").style.color="#990000"; 
  return;
  next i;
}
```

If any are false change the string to red, otherwise leave it the colour it is.